# presentModalViewController ontop of subview?

Tags: objective-c, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am trying to recreate the iPhone's tabView, but with my own style, buttons, etc. I didn't want to have to totally redo my app, so I simply added a view to the bottom like this `[window addSubview:theToolbar]; theToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 425, 320, 44);` in my appDelegate.

However, when trying to do this from a view inside a navigationController `theToolbar` is over it. Is there anyway to somehow present it to the front?

Here's my code to present the view:

```
AppSettingsController *appSettings = [[AppSettingsController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
appSettings.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:appSettings animated:YES];
[appSettings release];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's impossible show partial views of the viewcontroller. if your want to use the same toolbar, you should retain the toolbar to your appdelegate, and add the toolbar to each viewcontroller when it is in view.

or you should just use uiview's as viewcontrollers

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried that. When in put view controllers in my navigation controller, it slid left / right. I don't want that.

Comment: Put in in my navigationController instead. Thanks anyway.